# Is there a way to generate SQL scripts without using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to find a way to generate SQL scripts of a database without using any IDE. Any suggestions?

Comment: Powershell and SMO? https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+sql+generate+scripts

Comment: What kind of objects/scripts do you need? Please put some more effort and provide more details around what your issue is.

Comment: Depending on how old SQL is, SQL Pub Wizard: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5498

Comment: Are you unable to install SSMS? Is there a benefit to doing it without an IDE?

Comment: I am trying to generate SQL scripts for my own project, like a GUI for a database where a user doesn’t have to write any SQL query. They just add components (tables, relationships etc.) to the grid and then generate scripts of that. Just trying to know how to generate the scripts from the model without using any IDE